# what does exactlly simplepie set_timeout() work?

Tags: timeout, feed, simplepie

I want to know what does set_timeout (30) do?! I read document about this from simple pie docs

> Allows you to override the maximum amount of time spent waiting for
>   the remote feed's server to respond and send the feed back so that we
>   can begin processing it.

I don't understand what does it work!?! does it make to fast loading of website or not?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function will allow you to override the maximum amount of time that it waits for response from the server. Meaning, if the server sometimes has bad response time you can set it to wait longer for it. Instead of proceeding.

It can make it faster or slower. Depends on what you input in the parameters.

Comment: you mean if i set it to 30 second the feeds override start after 30 second right?!

Comment: No, it means the feed will wait for 30 seconds to get a response from the server. If that is what you are trying to do, that is not the current function. This will only let you change how much you wait for the server. If you are trying to setTimout() like in Javascript then you have the wrong function.

Comment: Let me clarify. If you want to set the maximum wait time for the server to be 30 seconds, use this function. If you want to wait 30 seconds to actually call the function, don't use this method.

Comment: no i want to wait 30 seconds to load completlly my website then feeds start updating.

Comment: actually i want at first my website load completlly then all rss feeds in main page start updating and i think timeout is for feeds fetch response time

Comment: Okay, if you are using Javascript, you can use setTimeout to wait to make the callback.

Comment: no i dont use javascript i use simplepie php codes 
$feed = new SimplePie();
$feed->set_feed_url(''.$link1.'');
$feed->enable_order_by_date(false);
$feed->set_cache_location($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/cache');
$feed->set_cache_duration($time);
$feed->handle_content_type();
$feed->set_timeout(10);
$feed->init();

Comment: Okay, so what you are doing is just setting the maximum amount to wait for the feed server. If it exceeds "10" time unit, it will go on evaluating the rest. If you want to wait for 10 seconds before initializing just use "sleep(time)".

Comment: It is a PHP function, just use "sleep()" instead of setTimeout.

Comment: @GabrielO.Nieves SimplePie set_timeout() is definitely not similar to sleep(). Instead, it's the timelimit for waiting the response from the server that the feed is requested after submitting the request. The idea is to avoid infinite stall in case remote server stalls but if the remote server responds faster than the timeout, there will not be any extra wait. Note that this timeout doesn't include the time needed for DNS request or the time needed to setup the TCP/IP connection or TLS handshake.